# Julia: Use of Distributed Arrays in Expressions

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, metaprogramming, distributed, julia

I am trying to spawn and evaluate expressions over different processes. The expressions contain local parts of distributed arrays, and this seems to create problems. For example,

```
addprocs(2)
x = [i for i = 1:10]
foo = @spawnat 2 quote
  out = x[1]
  for i = 2:5
    out += x[i]
  end
  out 
end
eval(fetch(foo))
```

gives, as expected,

```
Out [ ]: 15
```

However, if I try to replace the vector x with a distributed array dx and use only the local chunk in the expression, I get the following error.

```
# Construct a distributed array dx = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] # 
dx  = DArray(I->[i for i in I[1]], (10, ))    
dfoo = @spawnat 2 quote
  out = localpart(dx)[1]
  for i = 2:5
    out += localpart(dx)[i]
  end
  out 
end
eval(fetch(dfoo))


Out []: ERROR: BoundsError()
  while loading In[9], in expression starting on line 9

   in getindex at array.jl:246
   in anonymous at In[9]:2
```

I got the feeling that the problem is the localpart() which is not recognized when the expression is evaluated. 
Am I right?
Is there a way around this issue?

Thank you

Comment: `localpart()` returns only the chunk that is assigned to the process, so in your case it is an array with one element (because there are 10 parts) always indexed by 1. You get the bounds error because 2:5 are not included in the local part. I think the problem is that DArrays should be used to collect results (output), but you try to also use it as input in your computations.

Answer (score 1):

Here its the `quote` function that spawns at 2, not the evaluation itself. its like a misusage of `spawnat` macro.

look at this:

```
addprocs(2)
foo = @spawnat 2 quote
  myid()
end
eval(fetch(foo)) # => 1
```

And to calculate sum over distributed array: (there is nothing to do with @spawnat)

```
# Construct a distributed array dx = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] # 
dx  = DArray(I->[i for i in I[1]], (10, ))    
dfoo = @spawnat 2 quote
  sum(localpart(dx))
end
eval(fetch(dfoo))==sum(localpart(dx)) # => true
```